# Replace menu permalink/hyperlink with only menu name/slug

Tags: menus, permalinks, navigation

I don't know if i am asking this correctly, but i will try. ***I am doing this for history pushstate purpose.***

**Code** to get menu wihout `ul` and `li`:

```
$topmenu= array(
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $topmenu), '<a>');
```

At the moment, it gives mes only `<a>` tag with `href` as expected.

**For example:**

```
<a href="http://example.com/page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page2">Page 2</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page3">Page 3</a>
// etc
```

**My question:**

How to disable/hide full permalink/hyperlink in `href` attribute, but keep showing page slug?

**What i need for example:**

```
<a href="/page1"></a>
// etc
```

I tryed to make this work to changing `nav-menu-template.php`, but i failed.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all -

> I tryed to make this work to changing `nav-menu-template.php`

Never edit a core file! This is always a bad idea. At best, you will lose your changes when core updates.

To do this, you can use the [`nav_menu_link_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/) filter to modify the `href` attribute. This filter will be applied to each menu item individually.

In this example, we hook a function to the filter and `str_replace` the `home_url` with an empty string. So if our home URL is `http://example.com`, and the URL is `http://example.com/something`, the new value of `href` will be `/something`. We then `return` the modified attributes.

```
function wpdev_remove_home_url_from_menu_items( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['href'] = str_replace( home_url(), '', $atts['href'] );
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpdev_remove_home_url_from_menu_items', 10, 3 );
```

We only used the `$atts` argument in this case, but you'll note that there are two other arguments- the menu item object and menu args, in case you need to do any checking of specific menu items or menus in order to decide how to modify the attributes.

You can also use this filter to add additional attributes, like `data`, `rel`, and `target`.

Comment: Thank you. This is only for pushstate purpose. I never needed to do such things in wordpres, but now i need.. i need for myself :D Thanks again.